# Searching for Solr Stop words

Tags: solr, solr-schema

On of my solr fields is configured in the following manned,

```
<fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
 <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This works in cases where i don't want stemming, but now there is another use case which is causing a problem, people are beginning to seach for the following combinations,

- The Ivy : In this case results with just ivy is being returned, when the expected result would be with The. I understand that this is because of the stop word but is the way to achieve this. For example if they search for "the ivy" within quotes than this should work.
- (Mom & Me) OR ("mom and me"): In this case also & is dropped or results including both mom and me in some part of the statement is returned.

I am ok if only new data behaves in the right way but wouldnt be able to reindex. Also, would changing the schema.xml file trigger a full replication?

Regards,
Ayush

Answer (score 0):

You are using the white space tokenizer.
So "The Ivy" is slitted into 2 words.

You could use an less agressive tokenize an followed by the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` in order to activate the `protected="protwords.txt"` options, where you can set "the ivy" as an protected word so that solr will not tokenize that.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory